# SharePoint 2013 Authentication with Azure AD

Tags: active-directory, authentication, azure

I am attempting to establish authentication using Azure AD for a SharePoint 2013 site.

I followed the instructions in the article [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn635311(v=office.15).aspx).

Everything appears to work correctly as I am presented with a drop down that contains the Azure AD instance as an option and selecting this option redirects to the Azure AD sign in page.  What does not work correctly is after authenticating the login page (with the drop down list) is presented again.  This process repeats.  It seems as though Azure AD is aware that it has already issued a token as each subsequent trip to Azure AD does not prompt for authentication.

Hopefully, this is caused by something minor I have missed.  Any suggestions with regards to things to try will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a mismatch between the claims being sent from Azure ACS (step 3 in "Create Rule Group") and the claim mappings in SharePoint.

Comment: How might I verify that this or is not the issue?

Comment: Fiddler will show the token that is passed. Pretty hard to troubleshoot with no info...

Comment: I installed Fiddler and ran through the process again to capture traffic.  Based on my limited understanding, I started looking at the entry for the redirect to the "/_trust" URL.  Here I can see the SAML token which contains the three claims (upn, surname, and givenname) that I am sending with the expected values.  Further on in the list of entries, I see quite a few redirects that bounce around pages on the SharePoint site.  These redirects ultimately land back at the login page.  I am not sure what this means (if anything).

Comment: I got it working...sort of.  Perhaps you or another SharePoint *expert* can advise on what my observations mean.  The name of my server (WFE) is PK-SP-SPS-01.  The URL of the page I am trying to navigate to is https://pk-sp-sps-01/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx.  Without authentication (or at least without Azure AD authentication), if I navigate to https://pk-sp-sps-01/, I am ultimately redirected to the desired page.  With Azure AD authentication, this is not so.  If I navigate directly to the desired URL with Azure AD, it works.  What is the difference?  What is happening?

Comment: Continuing my previous comment, I have continued to dig.  Not recognizing the start.aspx page, I researched this a bit.  If I disable the Minimal Download option for the site and I navigate to https://pk-sp-sps-01/, Azure AD authentication works as expected.  However, I lose whatever benefits the Minimal Download option provides.  Are there any known issues in this area?  Sorry for the long posts.  I am just trying to learn and digest as much as I possibly can.

Comment: We disable "Minimal Download Strategy" by default, as all our evaluations of the runtime behaviour got us no better loadtimes at all. So I'd say, "Keep it switched of". We are on our way to connect to Azure AD at the moment, so I'll come back with anything handy we will discover.